# CollectionView selectItem tintColor is not highlighting or selecting the item

Tags: swift

I have this collection view in the `MenuClass` below:

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 230, green: 32, blue: 31, alpha: 1)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        //NOT WORKING
        let selectIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: selectIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 230, green: 32, blue: 31, alpha: 1)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName[indexPath.row])?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is the `MenuCell` class that I register for my collection view above:

```
class MenuCell: BaseCell {

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        return iv
    }()


    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            imageView.tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    override func setUpViews() {
        super.setUpViews()
        addSubview(imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `MenuBar` class in these lines of code inside the `init` method:

```
let selectIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
collectionView.selectItem(at: selectIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
```

It is not selecting the collection view first item and highlighting it white as the default selected item. I think it has to do with this line: `cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)` inside the `cellForItemAt` method in `MenuBar` and the overridden properties (`isSelected` and `isHighLighted`) inside the `MenuCell`.

I am not sure how this tinting works on the `imageView` (which I defined on the `MenuCell`) or if I am using the properties correctly. Can someone let me know how to use tinting and the properties to achieve this. With the home button highlighted white:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed this line inside the `cellForItemAt` method in MenuBar:

`cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName[indexPath.row])?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)`

to:

`cell.image = UIImage(named: imageName[indexPath.row])?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)`

By removing that `imageView` and for some reason it fixed the problem and selects the first item by default now. Can anyone let me know why this is working?

Answer (score 0):

The error was because you are setting the **tintColor** for the **imageView** instead of the **cell** itself in your MenuBar class inside the **collectionView (..., cellForItemAt...)**

**// wrong way**

```
cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)
```

**Set the tintColor to the cell and it would do**

**// Right way**

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(colorLiteralRed: 91, green: 14, blue: 13, alpha: 1)
```